# Question about PMF/PDF notation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In a probability course I'm watching, initially the notation introduced for conditional PMFs, where we're conditioning on event A was $P_{X|A}(x)$. But during a particular lecture, the notation he used was $P_{X|A}(x|A)$. Later in the class, the notation for when we're conditioning on a random variable $Y$ is introduced as $P_{X|Y}(x|y)$. Following the "function" analogy of the first notation, I might expect $P_{X|Y}(x,y)$. I'm confused about what the correct notation is.

Comment: There are no correct notation... it depend on how they define...

Comment: As Surb said, there are no "correct" notations because to actually make sense of conditional pdf or pmf, you need the notion of regular conditional probability and you really need rigorous measure theoratic definition of conditional expectation. Since, you might not know such things, it's better to have an intuitive idea of what the definition entails rather than overcumber yourself with notations. For example $P_{X|A}(x)=P(X=x, A)/P(A)$ or $P(X=x|A)$. And $P_{X|Y}(x,y)=f_{X,Y}(x,y)/f_{Y}(y)$ where $f_{X,Y}$ is the joint pdf and $f_{Y}$ is the pdf of $Y$ .

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron So is $P_{X|Y}(x,y)$ fine? It makes a whole lot more sense to me than $P_{X|Y}(x|y)$

Comment: @xasthor Like I said. As there are no standard notations which are completely rigorous at your level, it is fine as long as it makes sense to you intuitively. You should always be thinking of $P_{X|Y}$ as a pdf for each fixed $Y=y$ . To be slightly more technical, you should be thinking like this $P(X\in B | Y=y)=\int_{B} P_{X|Y=y}(x,y)\,dx $ for all "Borel" sets $B\subseteq \Bbb{R}$ ,  by sticking to your notation. Or if you prefer the cdf lingo, then $P(X\leq t| Y=y)=\int_{-\infty}^{t}P_{X|Y=y}(x,y)\,dx$ and this should be your conditional cdf.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Got it. Thanks